# DOM fixture for Protractor Jasmine test in Chrome

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

This might be too clever, but I have a working spec leveraging the `about:blank` "page" as a DOM fixture for Protractor + Jasmine in **Firefox**, but it fails in Chrome.

I load the `about:blank` page via the typical `browser.get('about:blank')`, disabling Angular, and then appending a set of links.

```javascript
    var redirects = [
      {
          'origin': '/short-url/',
          'destination': '/complete-url/?key=value'
      },
      {
          'origin': '/short-url/',
          'destination': '/complete-url/'
      }
    ];

    beforeAll(function () {
        isAngularPage(false);
        page.getRedirect('about:blank');
        browser.executeScript(function (redirects) {
            var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
            for (var r = 0, len = redirects.length; r < len; r++) {
                var anchor = document.createElement('a'),
                    text = document.createTextNode('link');
                anchor.setAttribute('class', 'redirect');
                anchor.setAttribute('href', redirects[r].origin);
                anchor.appendChild(text);
                fragment.appendChild(anchor);
            }
            document.body.appendChild(fragment);
            return document.body;
        }, redirects);
    });

    it('should have working redirects', function () {
        page.checkRedirects().then((responses) => {
            expect(responses).toEqual(redirects);
        });
    });
```

This is doing pretty much what it looks like it will do in the test. In the page object, leveraging `request-promise-native`, I get the defined elements, make the requests, and return the `origin` and `referer`

```javascript
this.checkRedirects = function () {
    return $$('.redirect').map(function (elem, index) {
        return elem.getAttribute('href').then((url) => {
            var headers = function (body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) {
                    var path = function(s) {
                        var tmp = s.replace(/^https:\/\/www.example.com/,'');
                        return tmp;
                    };
                    return {
                        'destination': path(response.request.uri.href),
                        'origin': path(response.request.headers['referer'])
                    };
                };
            var options = {
                baseUrl: 'https://www.example.com',
                method: 'GET',
                uri: url,
                resolveWithFullResponse: true,
                transform: headers
            };
            return request(options).then((response) => {
                return response;
            });
        });
    }).then((responses) => {
        return responses;
    });
};
```

The return `response` set should equal—Jasmine's `toEqual` does a deep match on objects—the defined `redirects` object of the spec.

As I said clever. **This works in Firefox**, but Chrome misbehaves... just a little bit. It actually updates the DOM, one can see this happen, knows that two (2) elements are present, but fails to `elem` `href` attribute. I know that it sees the two (2) elements because it executes the `request` twice on the `baseUrl`.

I'm aware of jasmine-fixture, etc., but those are jQuery tools, but just do what I'm doing in spec anyway.

**So, anyone want to take a stab at why Chrome is not behaving?**

Comment: just to check my sanity: I thought I would output the `browser.getPageSource()` and resolve that promise. Chrome and Firefox see the same thing. `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body><div id="redirects"><a class="redirect" href="/short-url/">link</a><br /><a class="redirect" href="/short-url/">link</a><br /></div></body></html>`

Comment: I may have fixed it... Chrome may not like the `href` attribute it a "domainless" page. It works just fine with `data-href` as the attribute key, e.g., `<a class="redirect" data-href="/short-url/">link</a>`